# Exit Pop Javascript not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, onunload

I have been trying to get this exit pop to work. So far I can get it to work on a Mac in FF, Chrome and Safari, but struggling with IE, FF, Chrome for Windows. These are two snippets that I have tried so far:

```
<script language=javascript>
function thankYou(){
var win=window.open("[url.com]", "_blank", "left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,scrollbars=1"); win.focus();  }
</script>

<body onUnload="thankYou()">
```

and

```
<SCRIPT>
function thankYou() {

var ConfirmStatus = confirm("We would love to receive your feedback on your experience of this page. Would you like to complete our short survey?");

if (ConfirmStatus == true) {
window.open("[url]", "win", "left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,scrollbars=1");
} else {
window.close();
}

}

window.onunload=thankYou;
</SCRIPT>
```

Not sure how to get it functioning on Windows. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
<body onUnload="thankYou()">
```

to:

```
<body onBeforeUnload="thankYou()">
```

and....

change:

```
window.onunload=thankYou;
```

to:

```
window.onbeforeunload=thankYou;
```